# Doxygen: Strips class-level documentation if a code snippet has an Objective-C interface

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

I'm documenting [this class](https://github.com/jasperblues/Typhoon/blob/master/Source/Factory/Provider/TyphoonFactoryProvider.h), but not having much luck with either Appledoc or Doxygen. . For this question I'd like to focus on the Doxygen issue.

Doxygen will stip-out (ignore) the class level intro - I mean all the bit that occurs just above @interface, if the code-snippets in the interface also contain an interface or protocol. . . to document this class properly we really need those snippets.

Is there a way to make doxygen treat these code snippets as snippets and normal snippets and not strip-out the class overview?

I've tries using some ~~~~~~ fence symbols, but this didn't work.

Here is what it [ended up looking like](http://www.typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/interface_typhoon_factory_provider.html).

Comment: Doesn't sound right, but I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. Can you give a more complete example (the "this class" link points to a non-existing page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to address this issue:

Use the following tags to tell Doxygen that a code fragment follows:

```
@code
@endcode
```

Another option is to sse @include directives, and set up an examples folder for to contain these as stand-alone files

Prior to this I was using the mark-down style syntax of indenting the code block. For this to work I had to escape the following symbols with a back-slash: '@', '<' and '>' . . technically this is a bug, as doxygen should treat the indentation as a code-block. . . this has been logged with the Doxygen team.